# DDD Bounded Contexts with Onion Architecture

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I have the following `Onion Architecture` framework.

- `Domain`

  - `Entities` - For my domain entities
  - `Interfaces` - For my domain interfaces
  - `Services`  - For my domain services
- `Infrastructure`

  - `Data` - For `Fluent NHibernate` persistence
  - `Interfaces` - For infrastructure interfaces
  - `Logging` - Just an interface for logging in case I want to switch out my logging library to something else.
  - `Dependency Resolution` - Most of my `IoC` registrations goes in here.
- `Services`

  - `Interfaces` - Application service interfaces goes in here, they will get implemented in the `UI` project.
- `Tests`

  - `Infrastructure Tests` - For testing infrastructure services etc.
  - `Domain Tests` - For testing domain models and services
- `Web`

  - `UI` - User interface project where I implement application services, user interface, etc ...

With `Domain Driven Development` one would identify the `Bounded Contexts`. Most of the literature on the internet states that each `Bounded Context` needs to be abstracted into their own project or namespace.

1. Is my approach then incorrect for having all my `Domain Models` in one project and all my `Domain Services` in another project? Does it really matter not having different bounded context's in different namespaces or projects?
2. If you have a `Model A` which is used my `Bounded Context A`, but  `Bounded Context B`, `Bounded Context C`, etc also needs to use the exact same `Model A`, Do you allow them to use that exact same model, or do you create a new model for each `Bounded Context`?

I am new to DDD so sorry if this question is a dumb question. I find myself understanding something better if I ask a question and get a good explanation as an answer.

Any Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is my approach then incorrect for having all my Domain Models in one project and all my Domain Services in another project? Does it really matter not having different bounded context's in different namespaces or projects?

1. Different namespaces is a conceptual *and* a practical solution, since otherwise you could have entity name collision when two neighboring concepts go by the same name in different subdomains.

   Different projects/solutions is more of an organizational choice on top of that. It makes things a bit easier if separate teams work on the BC's, and the separate binaries mean the BC's are more independently deployable.

> If you have a Model A which is used my Bounded Context A, but Bounded Context B, Bounded Context C, etc also needs to use the exact same Model A, Do you allow them to use that exact same model, or do you create a new model for each Bounded Context?

2. It would require some more domain analysis to tell, but the whole point of a Bounded Context is being able to view things from a totally different angle. In the rare cases when

   - the exact same entity is used in 3 different BC's
   - you don't see them evolving their own way in the future
   - the entity doesn't seem to naturally belong in a given BC

then you might want to use the Shared Kernel pattern. Otherwise, just copy the entity in each BC and let those live their own lives, or find the entity's true BC and link to its ID from other BC's.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely create 3 different models. BC 1, 2 & 3 might share the same concept behind `Model A` but it will be used in different part of the application. Drawing a simple [context map](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping) will help you to visualize models interactions and what's happening between the BCs.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it makes sense now. Just one question on top of this though, persistence related, for `Model A` in 3 `bounded contexts`, would you have 3 different mapping files, binding each context model to its own table, or have 1 mapping file?

Comment: Well, I would go with 3 different mapping files as well. Think of the _Customer_ concept. Depending on the context it might be a _prospective customer_, a _customer_ or a _client_. Those 3 models share the same idea but definitely don't share the same properties. There's no good unique model, no canonical model. DDD brings us the ability to create as much model as we have different contexts. But they will obviously share the same ID as the model goes through the contexts.

Comment: Thanx @MaxS-Betclic ill take all this in consideration as I improve my solution.